# What's the recursion equation of this program in the worst case?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

This is the program:

```
public class Program {
    public enum T { MIN, MAX } ;
    
    public static int mystery(int[] arr, int d, int f, T k ) {
        int answer = d ;
        if( d < f ) {
            int middle = ( d + f ) / 2 ;
            
            int max = mystery( arr, d, middle, T.MAX ) ;
            int min = mystery( arr, middle + 1, f, T.MIN ) ;
            
            if( k == T.MAX ) {
                answer = min ;
            } else {
                answer = max ;
            }
        }
        return answer ;
    }
    
    public static void main( String [ ] arg ) {
        int [ ] t = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 } ;
        System.out.println( mystery( t, 0, t.length - 1, T.MAX ) ) ;
    }
}
```

The program outputs: 5.

If the arr is of size n, i tried to calculate the recursion equation this way. We have two calls for the function, so it's `T(n) = 2 T(...) + ....`. We can notice that each time the array is divided by 2 so we can say `T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + ....`

Then since we have `if (k == T.MAX) ...`  we can tell that this runs 1 time in each call, so it's in O(1). Then the equation is `T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + 1` is this correct ?

Comment: Your equation looks right to me.

Comment: Your equation is right, but the n should be (f-d), not the size of arr.

Comment: @haoyuwang can you explain to me why it's (f-d) please ?

Comment: @asmazizou It's quite obvious. You divide the problem of [d,f] into [d,middle] and [middle,f]. The complexity has nothing to do with n. Of course caller can make f-d equals n, but you can't assume that.